# Capturing CAPTCHA image with Python

Tags: python

I tried using mechanize to see the URL of the image, but its a dynamic page generating a different image each time. I was wondering if there was any way to "capture" this image for viewing/saving.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to save the image would be to make a single call to the CATPCHA URL programatically, save the result, and then present that saved result to the user. The whole point of CAPTCHA is that each request generates a unique/different reponse/image.

Comment: I understand, but is there a way/library that shows me source code "as is" - that is, html, after all the processing. This way I might be able to grab the image much more easily.